# Perform a complicated calculation in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck trying to do calculations in sql query. I have table attendance which looks like this:

```
roll   |  sub_id  | status 
abc    |     1    |   1
abc    |     1    |   0
abc    |     2    |   1
xcv    |     1    |   1
abc    |     2    |   1
abc    |     1    |   1
lkj    |     2    |   0
```

This is an example of my table subject:

```
id  |  name 
1   |  Data Structure
2   |  Cloud Computing
```

I want to select distinct sub_id for particular roll and then count the number of status with 0 and status with 1 and link to the subject table and show their names.
and I want something like this :

```
roll  | sub_id |      name       | status with 0 | status with 1
abc   |   1    |Data Structure   |       1       |      2
abc   |   2    |Cloud Computing  |       0       |      2
```

Can someone explain me ?
How can I approach with the query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT
  a.roll, 
  a.sub_id, 
  b.name, 
  SUM(Case when status=0 then 1 else 0 end) as 'status with 0',
  SUM(Case when status=1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'status with 1'
FROM
  myTable a inner join subject b on
  a.sub_id = b.id
  group by a.roll, a.sub_id;
```

I made a fiddle for you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23d1d9/11/0

Comment: Thanks ! Nice approach.

Comment: This approach has a problem: The query is selecting a non-aggregate column (`b.name`), which does not appear in the `GROUP BY` clause, and it may not give the correct results in all cases.  This query would not even run on Oracle, SQL Server, and really any database besides MySQL.

Comment: I agree @TimBiegeleisen . It won't run out of the box on 5.7

Comment: This query is flawed

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional aggregation in a pivot query to get the output you want.  The subquery below calculates the tallies for `status` when the value is both `0` and `1`, for each each `roll`/`sub_id` group.

```
SELECT t1.roll,
       t1.sub_id,
       COALESCE(t2.name, 'name is NA'),
       t1.`status with 0`,
       t1.`status with 1`
FROM
(
    SELECT roll,
           sub_id,
           SUM(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `status with 0`,
           SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `status with 1`
    FROM attendance
    GROUP BY roll,
             sub_id
) t1
LEFT JOIN
subject t2
    ON t1.sub_id = t2.id
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: It gives syntax error near subject t2
(
    SELECT roll,
           sub_id,

Comment: This looks very much complex query. Isn't there any easier approach ?

Comment: @TomCruise This query really isn't that complex.